# Sum of indicated series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = 1, \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n = -1, a_1 = 2, b_1 = -3$

compute:
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n - 2b_n)$

I am a little bit stuck on what to do with all of the information given. My first idea:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n) - 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty ( 2b_n) = 1$

I don't think that this is right because I did not use all of the information, but what would be the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: the informations on $a_1$ and $b_1$ aren't usefull at all. Also $1 -2 \cdot (-1) = 3 $ not $1$.

Comment: Doesn't the use of the most simple expedient of simply plugging _the sums themselves_ in depend on the given two series being __absolutely__ convergent? I think you could devise a infinitude of _non_ -absolutely convergent series for which it would not be valid.

Answer (score 1):

We have :

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (a_n -2b_n) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n - 2 \cdot \sum_{n = 1}^\infty b_n$$

With the first two informations given we get :

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (a_n -2b_n) = 1 -2 \cdot (-1) = 3$$

Hence the informations on $a_1$ and $b_1$ aren't useful at all.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n - 2b_n)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n) - 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty ( b_n)\\
&=1+2=3
\end{align}